# Using the VLC ActiveX plugin to watch youtube videos C#

Tags: c#, vlc

Recently I have started messing around with the VLC ActiveX plugin trying to play youtube videos in a WindowsFormApplication and I have run into some issues that I couldn't find any mention of or solution to. For simplicity I made a new project to demonstrate my problems:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Player.playlist.play();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    url = textBox1.Text;
    Player.playlist.add(url);
    listBox1.Items.Add(url);
}
```

2 buttons, play and add to playlist.

Problem 1:
Audio cuts out a few seconds before the end of the video.
Problem 2:
I have been unable to get the control to play the next video in the playlist. It just reaches the end of the first video. If I click the play button again, it plays the first video. One thing I thought might be causing it was the AutoPlay property but it's set to true.
Problem 3:
The Player.playlist.next function, like most thing doesn't have a description and does not let me go to the next video in the playlist.
Problem 4:
The AutoLoop property does not work, assuming that it's supposed to get the control to loop a video.
Problems number 2 and 3 make me think that the songs aren't being added to the playlist correctly, but again I was unable to find any way to confirm or solve that issue.
Using VisualStudio 2015, VLC plugin version, as stated in the control properties, 3.0.1 Vetinari.

(edit) after testing I know that the videos are added to the playlist, but still it won't autoplay the next in playlist at the end.

Comment: Make a button and put the code that would play the second video in the playlist implicitly see if that works

Comment: I have managed to do playlist.PlayItem(1); and played the second video, so it is in the playlist, but it still won't play it automatically.

Comment: Well then make your own functionality to play the whole playlist

Comment: I probably will, but there is still the audio cutting out too early problem

Comment: Have you tried playing local videos ? does the audio also cuts at the end ?

Comment: I just tried it and the playlist.play(); does play all the videos i added, Now all the videos i tried are local so i would assume it's a connection problem